# opening multiple files in order of last changed

Tags: command-line

Suppose I want to look through a lot of files, one by one, using `vi *`. Is there an easy way to look a these files in non-alphabetical order, for example in order of newest or oldest first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope to be proven wrong but as far as I know there isn't an "easy" way to edit an arbitrarily sorted list of files. But if you are using a *nix system there is a solution that will work in many cases...

For the most part you're going to need to utilize other commands to build your sorted file list. Once you have that you can pass those files to `vim` on the command line and the order you specify is the order they'll be accessed during editing (with `:next`, `:last`, `:argdo`, etc.).

The most obvious way to sort files by common criteria is `ls`. See the `ls` man page for available flags but a couple key flags are:

- `-t` - sort by modification time (most recent first)
- `-S` - sort by file size (largest first)
- `-r` - reverse the current sort

Unfortunately, using the output of `ls` as input to other commands is generally a bad idea for reasons that are too involved to go into here except to say that one of the root problems is that all kinds of wacky characters are allowed in file names (newlines, tabs, control-characters, etc.). However, if you know your filenames are all made up of basic, printing characters than you can pipe `ls` output into vim like this:

```
ls -rt *.sh | xargs -r sh -c 'exec vim "$@" < /dev/tty' vim
```

Here `vim` will open with all `.sh` files in order of modification time, oldest first. I'd put the `xargs` part in a function...

```
xv() {
  xargs -r sh -c 'exec vim "$@" < /dev/tty' vim
}
```

...and then you can easily apply it to future commands such as...

```
find -name '*.txt' | xv
```

*But don't forget what I said about files with weird characters in their names!*

**Update:** If you're wondering what a proper solution looks like (that handles any legal filename) here's one that edits all `.sh` files in the current directory sorted in order of file size, largest first:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.sh' -printf "%s %f\0" | sort -zrn \
    | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"; ORS="\0"} {sub(/[0-9]* /, "", $0); print}' \
    | xargs -0 -r sh -c 'exec vim "$@" < /dev/tty' vim
```

A deep explanation is beyond the scope of this answer but a fundamental change is `find` emits *NUL* (`\0`) as "line" (record) separator rather than newline which is not possible with `ls`. That helps deal with filenames that contain newlines. Further...

- `find` : more precise output than `ls`; here the output is of form `size-bytes filename` + `NUL`
- `sort` : reverse numerical sort, `-z` to accept *NUL* terminator
- `awk` : strip off each size value
- `xargs` : like above but `-0` to accept *NUL* terminator

Anyways, this hardly meets OPs requirement of "an easy way" so it's been relegated to this postscript.